# Use the type of a class or interface method

Tags: angularjs, typescript

To give this question a bit of context, I have a child component which calls a callback provided by its parent. **This is a typical scenario in AngularJS.**

Since I'm using TypeScript, **I'd like to strongly type the callback in the child component**.

Here's the initial state without any strong typings:

```
class ParentComponentController {
  public parentMethod(param1: number, param2: string): boolean {
    return param1 > 0 && param2.length > 2;
  }
}

class ChildComponentController {
  constructor(private parentMethod: Function) {}

  public onCertainTrigger() {
    this.parentMethod(10, 'something');
  }
}
```

This is how I can achieve a strong typing but it seems so messy:

```
declare type parentMethod = (param1: number, param2: string) => boolean;

interface ICommonApi {
  parentMethod: parentMethod;
}

class ParentComponentController implements ICommonApi {
  public parentMethod(param1: number, param2: string): boolean {
    return param1 > 0 && param2.length > 2;
  }
}

class ChildComponentController {
  constructor(private parentMethod: parentMethod) { }

  public onCertainTrigger() {
    this.parentMethod(10, 'something');
  }
}
```

Ideally, I envision this as a one-liner. Is something like this possible?

```
class ParentComponentController   {
  public parentMethod(param1: number, param2: string): boolean {
    return param1 > 0 && param2.length > 2;
  }
}

class ChildComponentController {
  // This results in an error
  constructor(private parentMethod: ParentComponentController.parentMethod) {}

  public onCertainTrigger() {
    this.parentMethod(10, 'something');
  }
}
```

Comment: As explained in the answer, the second snippet is idiomatic to TS and already has least reasonable amount of code, while one-liner may be instructive but certainly not practical. Looking for one-liner here is basically code golf (which is offtopic on SO, by the way).

Comment: @estus Your answer may be idiomatic to TS, but passing callbacks is very common in JS. I want a short way of strongly typing the callback without having to create additional types and interfaces; a one-line achieves this beautifully. In my opinion, this is not "code golf" as I'm searching for a specific feature of TS.

Comment: This is how it is done in TS. If you need something to type against, this is a type and it should be explicitly defined. Doing the thing you're trying to do is a hack that has no benefits except it is shorter (which is the definition of code golf). If it is a type that is used only once, you should just specify callback type explicitly everywhere, `(n: number, s: string) => boolean`, I've updated the answer with explanation. The semantics for this is that it is not 'controller method type' but 'just some type which happens to be the same type as controller method'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is.

```
class ParentComponentController {
  public parentMethod(param1: number, param2: string): boolean {
    return param1 > 0 && param2.length > 2;
  }
}

class ChildComponentController {
  constructor(private parentMethod: typeof ParentComponentController.prototype.parentMethod) {}

  public onCertainTrigger() {
    this.parentMethod(10, 'something');
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a very strong contender. Can you provide some links to the official documentation explaining how `typeof` work in TypeScript?

Comment: See here https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/moving-types.html. Though this is not official, this documentation by @basarat is quite famous and reliable. I could not find a good official documentation about `typeof`.

Answer (score 2):

Still not one-liner, but something that can save you from explicitly maintaining parent method type:

```
declare let parentController: ParentComponentController;

class ChildComponentController {
    constructor(private parentMethod: typeof parentController.parentMethod) {}
}
```

Comment: I really like this approach! As you said, it's not a one-liner but it's very close to it (only 2 lines).

Answer (score 1):

As you have already declared a `type` `parentMethod`, you may also do something like below:

```
declare type parentMethod = (param1: number, param2: string) => boolean;

class ParentComponentController {

  //this is now a field of type parentMethod 
  public parentMethod: parentMethod = (param1: number, param2: string) =>
    param1 > 0 && param2.length > 2;
}

class ChildComponentController {
  constructor(private parentMethod: parentMethod) { }

  public onCertainTrigger() {
    this.parentMethod(10, 'something');
  }
}

new ChildComponentController(new ParentComponentController().parentMethod)
  .onCertainTrigger();
```

Here is the fiddle link for your referecne: https://jsfiddle.net/sayan751/ttmzzkg9/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a type alias with a namespace which isn't terribly great but will work:

```
class ParentComponentController {
  public parentMethod(param1: number, param2: string): boolean {
    return param1 > 0 && param2.length > 2;
  }
}
namespace ParentComponentController {
      export type parentMethod = (number, string) => boolean;
}

class ChildComponentController {
  // This results in an error
  constructor(private parentMethod: ParentComponentController.parentMethod) {}

  public onCertainTrigger() {
    this.parentMethod(10, 'something');
  }
}
```

Note that interfaces, as well as type aliases, do not exist at run-time. They are merely a design time construct.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of [Generics and Generic Constraints](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) is describing the relationship of types.

```
interface ICommonApi {
    parentMethod(param1: number, param2: string): boolean;
}

class ParentComponentController {
    public parentMethod(param1: number, param2: string): boolean {
        return param1 > 0 && param2.length > 2;
    }
}

class ChildComponentController<P extends ICommonApi> {
    constructor(private parent:P) { }

    public onCertainTrigger() {
        this.parent.parentMethod(10, 'something');
    }
}

let p = new ParentComponentController();
let c = new ChildComponentController(p);
```

If interface is simple:

```
class ParentComponentController {
    public parentMethod(param1: number, param2: string): boolean {
        return param1 > 0 && param2.length > 2;
    }
}

class ChildComponentController<P extends { parentMethod: (param1: number, param2: string) => boolean}> {
    constructor(private parent:P) { }

    public onCertainTrigger() {
        this.parent.parentMethod(10, 'something');
    }
}

let p = new ParentComponentController();
let c = new ChildComponentController(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'messy' snippet in the original post is the proper way to do this. This is what TypeScript best practices suggest. The fact is that `parentMethod` is a type, and wrapping it with some namespace like `ParentComponentController.parentMethod` doesn't do anything good.

It falls into the same case that the manual addresses in [*Needless Namespacing* section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#needless-namespacing):

> To reiterate why you shouldn’t try to namespace your module contents, the general idea of namespacing is to provide logical grouping of constructs and to prevent name collisions. Because the module file itself is already a logical grouping, and its top-level name is defined by the code that imports it, it’s unnecessary to use an additional module layer for exported objects.

Despite being a namespace in in the broad sense of the word, expected namespaced type like `ParentComponentController.parentMethod` type falls within the same principle, Occam's razor. Namespaced type provides unnecessary complexity while having no advantages for the design.

The code can use `T`-prefixed Hungarian notation for custom types in addition to `I`-prefixed interfaces. This is conventional for other OO languages, C# in particular (where TypeScript heavily borrows from). It should be also noticed that [well-known *Coding guidelines* document](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines) refers to the usage of prefixes in TypeScript code itself and doesn't prohibit Hungarian notation anywhere else.

So basically the preferable way stays unchanged, with possible use of `TParentMethod` instead of obscure `parentMethod` type for readability:

```
declare type TParentMethod = (param1: number, param2: string) => boolean;

interface ICommonApi {
  parentMethod: TParentMethod;
}

class ParentComponentController implements ICommonApi {
  public parentMethod(param1: number, param2: string): boolean { ... }
}

class ChildComponentController {
  constructor(private parentMethod: TParentMethod) { }
  ...
}
```

If callback function type occurs only once or twice and doesn't require a separate type to be defined, it is appropriate to specify function signature explicitly:

```
class ChildComponentController {
  constructor(private parentMethod: (n: number, s: string) => boolean) { }
  ...
}
```

This provides the necessary level of redundancy to keep code type safe.